# Is "off" also an acronym?

Tags: acronyms

I found the term *off* used in the following way (technical document):

> ... a total of two (2 off) Single radio channels ...

While the meaning seems pretty clear, I'd like to know what *off* stands for in such a context. I supposed it could be an acronym, but could not find any references.

Answer (score 2):

In this construction, *off* is redundant in meaning.

It is not an acronym.

It is occasionally used in specifications or ordering, after a number, to indicate that the quantity is of single items, not dozens, pairs, hundreds, etc. By doing this, the format *n+multiplier+description* is always satisfied, even when the *multiplier* is 1, so the reader knows that it isn't missing.

I believe it is less common in English now than 40-50 years ago, but is still used in other languages e.g. Swedish *stycken* (abbr. *st.*). It may have crept into your technical document as a translation, or by an author being more familiar with usage in another language.

Comment: *Off* also distinguishes a count of items from a quantity in units of mass, volume, length etc. - for example *Potatoes, large, 4 off* vs. *Potatoes, 4 lb.* You also find *Nos.* ('numbers') or *ea.* ('each') used in this sense. I think this usage is still common in English in inventory maintenance and ordering systems, building and engineering specifications, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The OED says (s.v. **off**, *adv., prep., n.1, and adj.*:)

> 12 Used with a preceding numeral to represent a quantity in production or manufacture, or an item or number of items so produced.
>   Usu. as one off: see one-off n.   Cf. once-off adj. and n. at once
>   adv., conj., adj., and n. Special uses 2.

with citations from 1934. "Kienzle printers. 6 off, surplus to manufacturing requirements." is an example from 1973